# Cannot login to Apache Usergrid deployed on Tomcat7

Tags: tomcat, cassandra, apigee, usergrid

I downloaded and built Apache Usergrid on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and deployed the ROOT.war on my local tomcat7 server as per instructions given at https://usergrid.incubator.apache.org/docs/deploy-local/. I copied usergrid-deployment.properties file to CATALINA_HOME/lib, restarted Tomcat server and am trying to test it using `http://localhost:8080/system/database/setup` as per the instructions.

I get a login screen that has the following text at the top: [ A username and password are being requested by `"http://localhost:8080"`. The site says: "Usergrid Authentication". ]. I try to login with the superuser id/pw as given in the usergrid-deployment.properties file but it does not recognize the id/pw and keeping throwing the same login screen. Did anyone encounter this problem? What am I missing? Do I need to add the superuser id/pw info to tomcat-users.xml? The instructions didn't ask for this. Even if I add what "role" would I use? Any help appreciated. BTW my Cassandra deployment works fine independent of Tomcat & Usergrid.

Answer (score 1):

this works for me.

1. you need edit a properties file under config package.

   usergrid/stack/config/src/main/resources/usergrid-default.properties
2. rebuild config, rest.
3. redeploy it.

Comment: remember clear the cache. rm -Rf tomcat/webapps/ROOT/

Answer (score 1):

The properties file name should be renamed as "usergrid-custom.properties" which you going to put in Tomcat/lib directory.

On the other way you can modify "usergrid/stack/config/src/main/resources/usergrid-default.properties" and rebuild config and then put "usergrid-config-1.0.0.jar" which is located "incubator-usergrid-master\stack\config\target" to your web application lib folder "Tomcat-Home\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\lib".

Answer (score 1):

I suffered from the same problem and only way I've found so far is to change usergrid-default.properties under stack/config/src/main/resources/usergrid-default.properties from source.

and then run "mvn clean install -DskipTests=true"

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

That login isn't part of Usergrid.  Do you perhaps have directory permissions set incorrectly on the directory that serves the install?  This sounds like a Tomcat protected directory problem, not a Usergrid login issue.

Answer (score 0):

The ROOT.war (build file of usergrid stack) file also needs to be stored into the CATLINA_BASE i.e 
(/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/) also.

Also change the ownership and access rights of tomcat folder(CATLINA_HOME and CATLINA_BASE) from root to complete free access (access level 777).

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy the `usergrid-custom.properties` file in this folder

> /usr/share/tomcat7/lib

Answer (score 0):

The login screen popping up repeatedly may indicate that it was unable to complete authentication or encountered issues while authenticating.

Ensure:

1. The usergrid-custom.properties is placed in your tomcat's lib
   folder
2. The username and password specified in it have no spaces
   at the end
3. You use the very same username and password that you
   specified

You may look up the logs for further information in case the issue persists