# Usergrid: Unable to Login to local Usergrid

Tags: apigee, usergrid, apigee-baas

I setup Usergrid on my local machine, however even after modifying the 'usergrid-default.properties' file and adding:

```
# SysAdmin login
usergrid.sysadmin.login.name=superuser      
usergrid.sysadmin.login.email=
usergrid.sysadmin.login.password=superpassword
usergrid.sysadmin.login.allowed=false
```

I am not able to login to the local instance. Even with the test/test password it is not allowing me in. IS there a trick I am missing?

-S

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/28692007/3917933

Comment: Same issue.  I'm not running a separate instance of Tomcat so there's nowhere to copy/paste the properties file as rockerston mentioned, just whatever runs as part of the maven build.  I'm on AWS EC2 and can get to domain.com:8080/status showing the server online.  I've also built portal and that is working fine as well.

The following files all exist in the resources folder all with the same default user/pass specified.

usergrid-deployment.properties
usergrid-default.properties
usergrid-custom.properties

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change the name of your properties file.

Try changing

usergrid-custom.properties 
to 
usergrid-deployment.properties

then restart tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Place "usergrid-custom.properties" in Tomcat's lib/ directory. Ensure that there are no spaces before or after the credentials in this file. Remove the ROOT/ directory in webapps/ and restart Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

```
usergrid.sysadmin.login.allowed = true
```